# How can I access to data are sending by android phone, in a voice call?

Tags: android

I want to access or edit voice call binary data on android, is it possible? If yes, How?

For example add some data to it and can receive it on receiver voice call.

(I assume that I have root access.)

Comment: you can do it only using root access. If any app could modify the voice call data, it would be enormous security issue, don't you think?

Comment: @Vladyslav Yes, I assume that I have root access. With this assumption, I asked this question.